# How to store the url of a web page in an sql database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have to store the link of a page in a database. The page is in my website.
As example:

I have to store the link of Result.aspx page in the database. How could I do this? I know that google.com can easily be stored and it's working with google.com, but I want to know how to do this with Result.aspx.

I will provide another example: there is an asp panel in my website and I have to store the urls of each row of menu and sub menu. These urls are also in my website like Default.aspx, Result.aspx etc.

If any question please ask.

Comment: most likely the answer is you can't. Web Form (which is horrible thing) does things in the background, feed them directly on the server side and then generate the page.

Comment: so how could i test my website is working properly or not?

Comment: depends on your implementation...with given info theres nothing I could say

Comment: An URL is really only a string..... just store the string? Any database can do that. ....

Comment: ok i will explain you with more details.. i have a site in my d folder (D:\site\test) and there is 2 pages in my website first is default.aspx(D:\site\test\Default.aspx) and second is Result.aspx (D:\site\test\Result.aspx)... and i just have to save the result.aspx url in the database so that if i click then it redirect me to Result.aspx.... i had tried this... 1. test\Result.aspx  .....   2. ~\test\Result.aspx if you have more question please ask. –

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear on me, but if you want to save your current page URL,

Feel free to use this.

```
    string URL = Path.GetFileName(Request.Path);  
    string sqlIns = "INSERT INTO table (url) VALUES (@url)";

        db.Open();
        try
        {
        SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sqlIns, db.Connection);
        cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@url", URL);

        cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmdIns.Dispose();
        cmdIns = null;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString(), ex);
        }
        finally
        {
        db.Close();
        }
```

Comment: ok i will explain you with more details..

i have a site in my d folder (D:\site\test) and there is 2 pages in my website first is default.aspx(D:\site\test\Default.aspx) and second is Result.aspx (D:\site\test\Result.aspx)...

and  i just have to save the result.aspx url in the database so that if i click then it redirect me to Result.aspx....

i had tried this...
1. test\Result.aspx
2. ~\test\Result.aspx

if you have more question please ask.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the problem is not with DB itself, it is with the relative url of the page. So, if your path is `http://myWebSite.com/Result.aspx` and `http://myWebSite.com/Default.aspx` then you should save string `"~/Default.aspx"`. If your path is like `http://myWebSite.com/someRoute/Result.aspx` and - then you should save string `"~/someRoute/Result.aspx"`.

To get this route you can use the following code:

```
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; // /someRoute/Result.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

it is simple...

private HtmlGenericControl LIList(string innerHtml, string rel, string url)
    {

```
    HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

    li.Attributes.Add("rel", rel);

    **li.InnerHtml = "<a href=" + url + ">" + innerHtml + "</a>";**

    return li;

}
```

this url is link which save in database.....